# Stop scroll bar from growing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got a page that scrolls horizontal to get to other pages (kinda like a slide show) but the way I do this my scroll bar makes itself smaller and bigger when you click on a button of the nav bar.
I want the scrollbar to start with the width from the page width.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    article.style.left = "-1000px";
        $('button').click(function () {
            $('button.current').removeClass('current');
            $(this).addClass('current');
        });
        $('#slide1').click(function () {
            article.style.left = "0";
        });
        $('#slide2').click(function () {
            article.style.left = "-500px";
        });
        $('#slide3').click(function () {
            article.style.left = "-1000px";
        });
        $('#slide4').click(function () {
            article.style.left = "-1500px";
        });
        $('#slide5').click(function () {
            article.style.left = "-2000px";
        });
 });
```

```css
* {
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html{
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 0 0 30px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
    background: #ffe7d9;
}

nav{
    width: 500px;
}

nav button{
    width: 18%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

article {
    width: 2500px;
    position: absolute;
    transition: 1s ease;
}

.page{
    width: 490px;
    height: 500px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
    <nav id="menu">
         <ul>
            <button id="slide1"><li>slide1</li></button>
            <button id="slide2"><li>slide2</li></button>
            <button id="slide3"><li>slide3(start)</li></button>
            <button id="slide4"><li>slide4</li></button>
            <button id="slide5"><li>slide5</li></button>
         </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
<article id='article'>
<div class='page' style='background-color: green;'></div>
<div class='page' style='background-color: red;'></div>
<div class='page' style='background-color: yellow;'></div>
<div class='page' style='background-color: black;'></div>
<div class='page' style='background-color: blue;'></div>
</article>
```

If you click on the button (`slide 1`, `slide2`, `slide3`, `slide4`, `slide5`) you will see that the scrollbar extends itself

Comment: start with `article.style.left = "0";` instead of `article.style.left = "-1000px";`, or you don't want scrollbar at all?(not sure I've understood correctly)

Comment: Using negative positioning for these kind of things is causing the weird scrollbar behaviour. What about using display: none; on the elements that have to be hidden and then write a transition to fake the scrolling effect. No messing around with positioning needed.

Comment: @sTx then how can I let it start on the 3rd slide?

Comment: @Minegolfer - no, I clearly didn't understood what you want; can you explain again how scrollbar should look like?

Comment: @Shilly I do need the scrollbar and if I would do that it will take the scroll bar away

Comment: @sTx the scrollbar should allways be the width which it is when you click on `slide1` and then not go smaller anymore when you click on `slide2` or `slide3` or other slides

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollLeft: $("#slide_3").offset().left
          }, 0);
          
        $("nav a").click(function(event){
            $("nav a").removeClass("selected");
            var clickedId = event.target.id;            
            var scrollTo = $("#slide_"+clickedId);
            $(this).addClass("selected");
           $('html,body').animate({
            scrollLeft: scrollTo.offset().left
          }, 1000);
        });
    
 });
```

```css
* {
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html{
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 0 0 30px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
    background: #ffe7d9;
}

nav{
    width: 500px;
}

nav a{
    width: 18%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
li{    display: inline;}
.selected{font-weight:bold;}
article {
    width: 2500px;
    position: absolute;
    transition: 1s ease;
}

.page{
    width: 450px;
    height: 500px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
    <nav id="menu">
         <ul>
            <li><a  id="1">slide1</a></li>
            <li><a  id="2">slide2</a></li>
            <li><a  id="3" class="selected">slide3</a></li>
            <li><a  id="4">slide4</a></li>
            <li><a  id="5">slide5</a></li>           
         </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
<article id='article'>
<div class='page' id="slide_1" style='background-color: green;'></div>
<div class='page' id="slide_2"  style='background-color: red;'></div>
<div class='page' id="slide_3"  style='background-color: yellow;'></div>
<div class='page' id="slide_4"  style='background-color: black;'></div>
<div class='page' id="slide_5"  style='background-color: blue;'></div>
</article>
```

Comment: I'm in a hurry, you can optimize and reduce jQuery selector calls